# Ionic2: How to make the ion-in ion-list item clickable?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a page to show a list of branches and select a branch to go to next page.

How to make the `ion-item` clickable, capture the click and select item?

I tried this code and it works. But, it shows a list of buttons.

```
 <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let branch of branchArray">
       <button ion-button full (click)='goHome(branch)'>
          {{branch.name}}
       </button>              
    </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think buttons getting displayed is an UI issue. Since I do not know the exact requirement of how it should be displayed, check out how to use `ion-list` [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#lists) as you want. You can also style it in CSS according to your requirement.

As far as the clickable part : what you have also works, but, make item clickable like this:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let branch of branchArray"  (click)='goHome(branch)'>
        <button ion-button full>
            {{branch.name}}
        </button>             
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: The button inside the item is not needed as item itself clickable. I was on the impression that it needs a button to make it clickable.

Comment: Ok. Remember, any container, like `<div>`,` <p>`,`<b>`,`<ion-card>`, etc can be made clickable. :)

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer is not completely correct. The Ionic documentation says (now, might have been different at the time of answer):

> A basic item should be written as a `<ion-item>` element when it is not clickable.

and later

> The attribute ion-item should be added to a `<button>` when the item can be clicked or tapped.

So you should use this code instead:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item button *ngFor="let branch of branchArray"  (click)='goHome(branch)'>
        <!-- Inner code here depending on your styling. -->
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

This changes the semantics of the ion-item and then styles are alse updated accordingly: You do not need to hack your CSS files.

Comment: Yup, this is written in the official docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/item/Item/